# Getting these errors while installing packages on react native

Tags: react-native, module, package, dependencies, linear-gradients

I am getting these errors while installing react-native-linear-gradient, even for uninstalling and updating I am getting the same errors.

```
    PS C:\Users\sawan\OneDrive\Desktop\WorkoutApp\workout> npm install react-native-linear-gradient
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-windows@0.71.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.8
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
    npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.8" from react-native-paper@5.1.4
    npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-paper
    npm ERR!       peer react-native-paper@"*" from react-native-material-dropdown-v2-fixed@0.11.3
    npm ERR!       node_modules/react-native-material-dropdown-v2-fixed
    npm ERR!         react-native-material-dropdown-v2-fixed@"^0.11.3" from the root project
    npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@6.5.2
    npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/bottom-tabs
    npm ERR!     @react-navigation/bottom-tabs@"^6.5.2" from the root project
    npm ERR!   23 more (@react-navigation/core, @react-navigation/elements, ...)
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native-windows@0.71.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-windows
    npm ERR!   peer react-native-windows@">=0.63.3" from react-native-orientation-locker@1.5.0
    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-orientation-locker
    npm ERR!     react-native-orientation-locker@"^1.5.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   peer react@"18.2.0" from react-native-windows@0.71.0
    npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-windows
    npm ERR!     peer react-native-windows@">=0.63.3" from react-native-orientation-locker@1.5.0
    npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-orientation-locker
    npm ERR!       react-native-orientation-locker@"^1.5.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! See C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\sawan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-02-01T07_19_34_419Z-debug-0.log
```

Before this I tried running the project, then I started getting another error saying so and so module is not present within the project or in node_modules.

Here is the error:

```
error: Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-linear-gradient from C:\Users\sawan\OneDrive\Desktop\WorkoutApp\workout\src\screens\SignInScreen\SignInScreen.js: react-native-linear-gradient could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
   7 | import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton';
   8 | import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
>  9 | import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
     |                             ^
  10 |
  11 | const API_URL = Platform.OS === 'android' ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'http://192.168.2.143:3000';
  12 |
```

I've tried using --force but after running it again it shows the same error. Do I have to reinstall all my packages again or do I have to change the react version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to stop the application and do the below process:

- remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`
- run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps`
- rerun application