# React-Native dead after update: Error - Unable to resolve module react-native-gesture-handler

Tags: ios, react-native

Just finished updating from RN 0.69.8 to RN 0.71.3 and I'm having some issues. RN Gesture handler is perfectly installed and in my node-modules file, I've followed all update instructions to the tee, yet I still get

```
Error: Unable to resolve module react-native-gesture-handler from /Users/ethan/LayrApp/index.tsx: react-native-gesture-handler could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../node_modules
   6 | import App from './App';
   7 | import { name as appName } from './app.json';
>  8 | import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
     |         ^
   9 |
  10 | AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Coming from the index.tsx file. I'm pretty lost at this point, tried rebuilding the packages from scratch, going through all the pods and checking if everything was in order, etc.

Any ideas? Currently glued to my laptop trying to resolve this.

BTW: Trying to comment out the rn gesture handler and running just yields these results:

```
Error: Unable to resolve module ./app.json from /Users/ethan/Downloads/LayrApp/index.tsx:

None of these files exist:
  * app.json(.native|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * app.json/index(.native|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
   5 | import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
   6 | import App from './App';
>  7 | import { name as appName } from './app.json';
     |                                  ^
   8 | // import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
   9 |
  10 | AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Looks like I'm in a little error loop :(

Lmk if you guys have any ideas, and thank's in advance!

Comment: Hey! I don't know which way did you upgrade your RN version, but I usually do it using [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-helper), checking and modifying file by file. After this, I remove the dependencies folders, reinstall the dependencies, and run the project. Did you try this way?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove "resolver" object from "metro.config.js" file. Try this solution https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36676#issuecomment-1495432504