# React Dependencies Error When i Install Somenthing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm working on React from couple months ago, and some people shared me a "Finished" project, when i try to install whatever dependency by npm it give me multiple errors and i have to install it forcing or by yarn, but i want to clean that errors. For what i can see, are versions conflict, but if anyone know why and how to resolvit or how to update the depencies, i would be really thankfull!.

[image: Console]

I have tried removing node_modules and installing it again. Even when i execuute the npm install command for the first time, it give me that errors.

Comment: Along with node_modules, deleting package-lock.json helps at times. Try giving a shot with that as well.

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75306961/20860690?

Comment: Yes! i tried deleting package-lock.json and running npm i --legacy-peer-deps, the command works without errors, but when i tried to install another thing it gives me that error list.