# Dependency error installing react native firebase crashlytics

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I try installing firebase crashlytics in my react native project, I get the following error:

```
code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: wooappapp@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: @react-native-firebase/app@16.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/app@"^16.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @react-native-firebase/app@"17.3.2" from @react-native-firebase/crashlytics@17.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-firebase/crashlytics
npm ERR!   @react-native-firebase/crashlytics@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

This is my (part) of my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^16.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.68.5",
  },
```

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75306961/20860690

Answer (score 2):

Error is telling you that crashlytics needs a newer version of `@react-native-firebase/app`.....it needs `17.3.2` but you have `16.5.0`.  You need to upgrade to most recent version for your existing 3 RN Firebase libraries.
I find easiest way it to uninstall then reinstall.....thus terminal commands would be as follows:

```
npm uninstall @react-native-firebase/app --save
npm uninstall @react-native-firebase/auth --save
npm uninstall @react-native-firebase/messaging --save
npm install @react-native-firebase/app --save
npm install @react-native-firebase/auth --save
npm install @react-native-firebase/messasging --save
npm install @react-native-firebase/crashlytics --save
```

Comment: i had the same error with version 19.0.1 and it was asking for 19.1.1. I installed the version matching the others  npm install react-native-firebase/crashlytics@19.0.1