# How do I import a library into my React project without getting this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, react-icons

I've tried multiple times to import a library to my React project, but every time I try, an error like this pops up:

```
# npm resolution error report

While resolving: react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.1
Found: react@18.2.0
node_modules/react
  peer react@">= 16" from @heroicons/react@2.0.18
  node_modules/@heroicons/react
    @heroicons/react@"^2.0.18" from the root project
  peerOptional react@"^18.0.0" from framer-motion@11.0.8
  node_modules/framer-motion
    framer-motion@"^11.0.8" from the root project
  peer react@"^18.2.0" from next@14.0.2
  node_modules/next
    next@"^14.0.2" from the root project
  peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
  node_modules/react-dom
    peerOptional react-dom@"^18.0.0" from framer-motion@11.0.8
    node_modules/framer-motion
      framer-motion@"^11.0.8" from the root project
    peer react-dom@"^18.2.0" from next@14.0.2
    node_modules/next
      next@"^14.0.2" from the root project
    react-dom@"^18.2.0" from the root project
  peer react@">= 16.8.0 || 17.x.x || ^18.0.0-0" from styled-jsx@5.1.1
  node_modules/styled-jsx
    styled-jsx@"5.1.1" from next@14.0.2
    node_modules/next
      next@"^14.0.2" from the root project
  react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
  peer react@"*" from react-icons@5.0.1
  node_modules/react-icons
    react-icons@"*" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.1
node_modules/react-server-dom-webpack
  react-server-dom-webpack@"^0.0.1" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
node_modules/react
  peer react@"^17.0.0" from react-server-dom-webpack@0.0.1
  node_modules/react-server-dom-webpack
    react-server-dom-webpack@"^0.0.1" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I have no idea how to fix it, and it seems like ChatGBT doesn't know either.

I tried to import the react-icons library and expected it to be installed without an error.

Comment: Have you tried adding `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` to your package installation command like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/75306961/20860690

Comment: Yeah, I guess that works, but I just feel like it doesn't solve the error thing, because it happens every time I try to import a library, and I just have no idea why it happens.